# Strange similar approximations of pi and e

Tags: approximation, pi, eulers-number-e

I just discovered these after approximation by Borwein and Bailey for $\pi$

[image: Approximation of pi]

[image: Approximation of e]

And I'm assuming the latter just converges to e as the power of x increases although I'm not sure how to go about it (even knowing $lim (1+1/x)^x = e$, obviously, it seems non-trivial as I can't just ignore the "1+" but I'm not a mathematician and I am probably overlooking something trivial).

Kind of a peculiar first result, no? Is there any literature about these, or some insights?

Answer (score 2):

For large $n$ and $x>1$, $(1+x^{-n})^{1+x^n}\approx(1+x^{-n})^{x^n}\approx e$, so the fixed point approximates $e$.

For the case $n=1$, a root $>1$ of $(1+x^{-1})^x=x^2/(x+1)$ will be a poor approximation for $e$, but will be a better approximation for the positive root of $x^2/(x+1)=e$, which is $\tfrac12(e+\sqrt{e^2+4e})\approx3.5$. This is still not a great approximation, as $x$ isn't large enough for $(1+x^{-1})^x$ to be very close to $e$.

We can iteratively improve this reasoning, but the result approximating $\pi$ looks like a coincidence. It's better to ask why the $n$ for which $\pi$ is the root is close to $1$.

Comment: Thx, I'm not sure why I got confused with the expansion towards e.

I'll wait to accept answer in case someone brings more insights as to why "pi" could be less than a coincidence - although I have no idea what kind of argument would be able to show that.

Comment: @buddhabrot About the only argument I can think of would be one that exploits the size of $\pi-e$. For example, I can see someone arguing $x-e\approx\tfrac12$, but getting a few decimal places of $\pi$ right is another matter. To be honest, I think the _real_ lesson here is "if you generalize enough problems whose answer is $e$ or approximately $e$, you'll get a nice special case where it's approximately $\pi$, because $\pi-e\approx\tfrac12$".